# Alias an sqlalchemy.text object

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Im trying to allow users to input query in the UI and then add it to the FROM clause of my sqlalchemy.
After seeing the `from_self` function on the query object in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html), I tried:

```
Query.from_statement(text("select * from test_table")).from_self()
```

and:

```
alias(text("select * from test_table"), name="some_name")
```

and:

```
text("select * from test_table").label(name="some_name")
```

None of these worked. 
Im trying to get a query like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM test_table) AS some_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of hassling, found a way to do so like this:

```
alias(TextAsFrom(text("SELECT * FROM test_table"), columns), name='some_name')
```

This is possible due to the TextAsFrom that can be found deep in the docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html?highlight=textasfrom#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextAsFrom). One con to this method is that you must provide column objects for this to work (you can see the columns variable in my code.) I worked around this by querying the table only for the columns and then creating a column object for each column in the table.

Cheers.

Comment: The usual way to produce a `TextAsFrom` would seem to be `text("...").columns(*columns).alias('some_name')`, instead of directly creating it: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause.columns. It is also covered in the tutorial: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#specifying-result-column-behaviors